# jQuery Sort Table - Change Order on Load

Tags: jquery

I came upon this JS Fiddle, which is great. What changes would I need to make for it to sort the third column in a descending order on the page load?

```
$(document).on('click', 'th', function() {
  var table = $(this).parents('table').eq(0);
  var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer($(this).index()));
  this.asc = !this.asc;
  if (!this.asc) {
    rows = rows.reverse();
  }
  table.children('tbody').empty().html(rows);
});

function comparer(index) {
  return function(a, b) {
    var valA = getCellValue(a, index),
      valB = getCellValue(b, index);
    return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ?
      valA - valB : valA.localeCompare(valB);
  };
}

function getCellValue(row, index) {
  return $(row).children('td').eq(index).text();
}
```

[Here is the link to the Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/zhantong/zpbw3h7t/)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your sorting logic in a separate function and call that function on $(document).ready()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  sort();
});

$(document).on('click', 'th', function() {
  sort();
});

function sort() {
    var table = $('table').eq(0);
    var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer($(this).index()));
    this.asc = !this.asc;
    if (!this.asc) {
      rows = rows.reverse();
    }
    table.children('tbody').empty().html(rows);
}

function comparer(index) {
  return function(a, b) {
    var valA = getCellValue(a, index),
      valB = getCellValue(b, index);
    return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ?
      valA - valB : valA.localeCompare(valB);
  };
}

function getCellValue(row, index) {
  return $(row).children('td').eq(index).text();
}
```